# Cells referenced in formula not displaying

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Usually when I have a simple formula in Excel `(A1+A2)` if I click in cell containing the formula a blue and a pink box will highlight cells `A1` and `A2` and I can move the reference point around if I like.

Recently someone tried to use my laptop and hit a bunch of shortcuts and one has disabled this feature.

Now when I click on a cell the reference points are no longer highlighted. The formula cell still displays the product of the calculation.

Any ideas what happened?

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Once the proper options have been selected, clicking on a formula cell should yield:

[image]

If you now touch <kbd>F2</kbd> or click in the Formula Bar, you should see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File -> Options -> Advanced` and check the **Enable fill handle and cell drag-and-drop** option.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that option was already selected

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the cell is press `F2` that should bring up the cell references.

If that does not work going to `File -> Options -> Advanced` and check*Enable fill handle and cell drag-and-drop* and *Allow editing directly in cells*. If you've checked these two and they still do not work, you can compare your settings with mine below and see if they are the same.

[Advanced Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zkgd.png)